# I want to customize my fron-page.php in dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I started learnin wordpress recently. 
I created a single page website and then installed wordpress and made a front-page.php and updated it with my website code.
My problem is that I want it to show in dashboard for example in pages section so I can for example add comments section to it but I can't find it in dashboard.
Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to edit front-page.php

from WordPress dashboard

```
Appearance->Editor
```

You can find front-page.php, you can edit and change as per your requirement.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I edit it in my code editor but I want to manage it in dashboard but It is not in my pages section for example to add comment

Comment: You have to assign front-page as a home page

Comment: In home page setting when I select static webpage my custom front-page.php is missing and only the pages that I created in dashboard ar showing

Comment: You have to create home page and then  go to: Appereance-> Customize->Homepage settings-> select static page and then select home page which you have created from  pages.

Comment: Can't I Just make the home page in front-page.php? If I add my html/php code to the edit section of pages the images and scripts won't work.

Comment: Lets come in chat, if possible?

Comment: I only have 18 reputation

Comment: Because it's 2min work for me if i have admin credentials.

Comment: You should at least upvote, for developer encouragement.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170829/discussion-between-ppl-and-soheilps).